# Python --version Windows only returns word Python

Tags: python, windows

So the question is pretty short but I couldn't find the answer yet. I want to check my python version in the terminal on Windows:

```
python --version
Python
```

the same output for python3 --version, python -V and so on. What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you please try 'py -V' or 'py --version'

Comment: That works!! Thanks! Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

`python --version` is the **MacOS** and **Linux** command, for **windows 10** try using `py --version`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use

```
'py --version' or 'py -V'
```

`'Python --version' and 'Python -V'` should also work.

Try going through this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/beginners

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall python, May be a corrupted installation

Answer (score 0):

probably environment variable isn't set up correctly
check if it is `D:\python\Scripts\;D:\python\;`